# no `PROT_READ` in `sys::mman` error while using nix mmap

Tags: rust

I have the following two lines in my code:

```
use nix::sys::mman;
use mman::{PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, MAP_ANON, MAP_NORESERVE};
```

When I build my code, I get `no PROT_READ in sys::mman` error and similar errors for the other flags. How should I use `MmapProt` and `MmapFlag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation indicates that these are *associated constants* underneath [`ProtFlags`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.10.0/nix/sys/mman/struct.ProtFlags.html) and [`MapFlags`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.10.0/nix/sys/mman/struct.MapFlags.html), not constants in the `mman` module.

```
extern crate nix;

use nix::sys::mman::{MapFlags, ProtFlags};

fn main() {
    ProtFlags::PROT_READ;
    ProtFlags::PROT_WRITE;
    MapFlags::MAP_PRIVATE;
    MapFlags::MAP_ANON;
    MapFlags::MAP_NORESERVE;
}
```